# Will the Battleship reappear if you miss it once?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I want to farm the Blaster Launcher before I finish the game. The Battleship appeared once when I was in the process of rearming the Firestorm I had over that area and my 2 regular interceptors were unable to take it down, and the Battleship got away.

Will it reappear in my game, or did I miss my one chance to get it? I'm been scanning for ~3 months and haven't seen it since.

Comment: I memory serves me (quick wiki run gives nothing), aliens send a lesser UFO (like, a little Barge :-) ) to find satellites, and then the Battleship comes with Satellite Destruction mission. Did you see UFOs on Satellite Hunt mission or something?

Comment: You can also "bait" a battleship to appear by simply not responding to the scouting UFOs.

Comment: @RavenDreamer - thanks! That was very useful. Can you add that as a full answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The next time you detect a UFO (landed or otherwise), simply let it go along its merry way. When it escapes, uncontested and unmolested, it will trigger a battleship to spawn. As far as I've seen, battleships are the *only* ships that try to shoot down satellites, so you can trigger their appearance if you can entice the aliens to look for your satellites. (Though why they only look for satellites when they *don't* get intercepted seems kinda weird)

I was achievement farming on Easy, and was bored waiting for my *first* battleship to show up - so I baited one out using the above method. One EMP equipped Firestorm later, my squaddies were well on their way to blaster launchers and fusion lances.

Comment: +1 Preparing my end-game squad and didn't see a battleship in months of Psi training ... until I saw this advice.  Ignored one scout and a battleship came after my "undefended" satellite.  EMP Firestorm took it down and my somewhat overtrained crew are now preparing to massacre some aliens.

Comment: @Andrew there's no such thing as overtrained... the RNG will rape them... xD

Answer (score 6):

Yes, more than one battleship will appear during the game, though they are fairly rare.

In my last game, playing on normal difficulty, I had one appear as a landed ship mission, and my squad was nearly wiped out early on and had to abandon, but a few months later, I was able to shoot one down and take it, with better tactics and a better trained squad.