# Why would I want my satellites to be 'stealthy'?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I'm part way through my first playthrough of XCom on Normal difficulty and have unlocked the Foundry project for 'Stealth Satellites'.

The description text says something about it making satellites harder for enemy UFOs to detect. Why is that a good thing? I have interceptors over the continents where I have satellites and if a UFO comes I can normally shoot it down and get a UFO mission, which tend to provide benefits without the costs of abduction missions for example.

This question is almost the opposite of [What is the point of using interceptors to attack UFOs?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87386/what-is-the-point-of-using-interceptors-to-attack-ufos)

Anyone do this project and get a benefit from it? Answers without spoilers preferred...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not want to spoil the game much, but in late-game you will have certain big UFOs turn up that you may or may not be ready for. These will not be taken down by your interceptors so easily and a few showings from these might even lead to your entire Interceptor fleet getting wiped out or them being just plain useless.

This will cause you to leave some of these UFOs alone without doing anything. This usually has a repercussion of them attacking the satellites. A successful satellite take down will increase panic in the country by 2 points. Again, this may or may not overwhelm you with panic-stricken countries, depending on how well you stand in game.

So when you do reach this stage you want to have those satellites survive so that they do not drive panic up anymore than you want. This is the only reason you would want stealthy satellites.

Personally I would rather have satellites in stock ready to launch so that when one gets taken down I can launch another and get panic reduction in the area. Especially effective if panic is almost maxed out in the area.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and for not giving away too much about the late game :)

Comment: Also note that if you "need" a battleship a highly visible satellite is actually excellent bait: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/91635/88

Answer (score 2):

UFOs can attack your satellites if you choose to ignore them or unable to shoot down. There is a chance that UFO will come to destroy one of satellites on that continent. With "stealth satellites" there is a chance that sat not being detected by this ignored UFO.

Comment: The bit I don't understand is whether having stealth satellites makes the UFO missions less common - where the UFO missions in general seem like a good thing.

Comment: @JonathanJ I think you read the description wrong. Having stealth satellites does NOT make the satellite have a harder time to detect UFOs.

Comment: @rikitikitik I think they are asking if having stealth satellites makes UFO's less likely to show up overall. It doesn't matter if you have the same chance to detect one if there are less. (I don't play the game but that's what his concern sounds like to me.)

Comment: @Reafexus but why would he think from the description that that is the case? That's why I'm suggesting he may have interpreted the description incorrectly

Comment: This: "The bit I don't understand is whether having stealth satellites makes the UFO missions less common", combined with: "making satellites harder for enemy UFOs to detect" makes me think that OP thinks UFO's won't come to 'investigate' your planet as often if they don't detect any satellites if they are all stealthed

Comment: @Reafexus first, a satellite is launched per country, and there's only one planet in the entire game. Second, there's nothing that would suggest that what you said is the case. UFOs already fly above a country even before you launch a satellite on that country. If the OP thinks that having a satellite increases the UFO activity on that country and getting them stealthed decreases it, he should have pointed that out explicitly in his question.

Comment: @Reafexus is right in what I was asking. I might be off-base there, but it's hard to know without testing. Anecdotally, I've had 5 missions to intercept and shoot down UFOs over continents where I have satellites (2 and now 3 out of the 5 continents) and only 1 landing on the (3, now 2 continents) where I don't have satellites.

Comment: @JonathanJ Then you should add that to your question. Better yet, ask a new one.